# Why css styles are not applying for matching rows in javascript?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

If records are matching with searchtext need to hightlight that entire row but not applying that css style.

My javascript function

```
  $(function () {
    grid = $('#tblsearchresult tbody');
    // handle search fields key up event
    $('#search-term').keyup(function (e) {
      text = $(this).val().trim(); // grab search term
      if (text.length > 1) {
        grid.find('tr:has(td)').css({ background: "" });
        grid.find('tr').show();
        // iterate through all grid rows
        grid.find('tr').each(function (i) {
          // check to see if search term matches ApplicationName column
          if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase().match(text.toUpperCase()))
              $(this).addClass('result');
          // $(this).css({ background: "#A4D3EE" });
          // check to see if search term matches RoleName column
          if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase().match(text.toUpperCase()))
              $(this).addClass('result');
        });
      }
      else {
        grid.find('tr:has(td)').css({ background: "" });
        grid.find('tr').show();
      } // if no matching name is found, show all rows
    });
  });
  $('table').tablesorter();
```

My CSS :

```
  table.tablesorter tbody td.result {
    background: #A4D3EE;
  }
  table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #8dbdd8;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  table.tablesorter thead tr .header:not(.nosort) {
    background-image: url('/sorter/bg.gif');  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  table.tablesorter tbody td {
    background-color: rgb(239, 243, 251);
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;

    vertical-align: top;
  }
  table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
    background-color:#F0F0F6;
  }
  table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp:not(.nosort) {
    background-image: url('/sorter/asc.gif'); 
  }
  table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown:not(.nosort) {
    background-image: url('/sorter/desc.gif'); 
  }
  table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-color: #8dbdd8;
  }
```

UI Design :

```
<table id="tblsearchresult" class="tablesorter">
  <thead> 
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Table Data :

```
applicationame   role
application1     appadministrator
app              developer
application2      tester
```

if i given 'app'as search text need to highlight secondrow only .highlightling firstrow also because 'app' is there in role of firstrow..exact match should be highlight on every rows.please tell me.

Please check my code i need to highlight the matching record row .if searchtext matching with table column data need to highlight the entire row.but not applying css in above code.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: @abhitalks this scenario different.i need to highlight entire row.

Comment: create a fiddle if you need faster replies

Comment: i don't how to create it.please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not applying the result class to the correct element. In your CSS, the following line defines the result class for TDs:

> table.tablesorter tbody td.result

But in your javascript, this line will apply it to the table row:

> $(this).addClass('result');

So by changing this line to

> $(this).children('td').addClass('result');

you should be okay.

**Update:**
Based on your feedback, I've created an example on jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/kUxNj/4/

> ```
>                 // check to see if search term matches ApplicationName column
>                 if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase() === text.toUpperCase())
>                     $(this).children('td').addClass('result');
>                 // check to see if search term matches RoleName column
>                 if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase() === text.toUpperCase())
>                     $(this).children('td').addClass('result');
> ```

Comment: for single columns it is working fine.my table having 4 columns in that case i am not getting exact match.i need exact match on all rows.

Comment: can you check my sample data in above code.if i search with 'app' need to highlight 2nd row only.but highlighting 1 st row also because in 1 st row role data as appadminstrator.it's not correct.exact match records only need to highlight.in above code 2 characters are matching in every column highlight that row.

Comment: If you only want to match strings that are exactly same (ignoring the case) then instead of this:
$(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase().match(text.toUpperCase())
You should do something like this:
$(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase() === text.toUpperCase()

(Same for the second case)

Comment: if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase() === (text.toUpperCase()))
                        $(this).children('td').addClass('result');              
                        // $(this).css({ background: "#A4D3EE" });
                        // check to see if search term matches RoleName column
                    if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase() === (text.toUpperCase()))
                        $(this).children('td').addClass('result');
                          //  $(this).addClass('result');

Comment: Follow the link in my updated post, You will see a working implementation of it. And from there you can go on and customize it, however you want.

Comment: please how to achieve this using keyup textbox function.

Comment: hi thanks for ur help sorry for that if we given 'app' as search text need to highlight all rows.if type application1 then need to highlight firstrow only like that need to implement.if he type application2 need to show 3rd row only.please kindly help me.

Comment: like as need to search all rows data in table.please check my table data in above.

Comment: I can't solve all your problems, sorry. This question is answered however, so please accept the answer and in case you have other issues, open new ones. (but to achieve what you want, you could simply hide all the rows where the result class has not been set)

Comment: ah, whatever, we're just before holidays, so I've updated the example on jsfiddle, to do what you need :)